# Nested Accordions Overlapping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create some nested accordions using CSS, html, and Javascript. Everything was working as intended until I attempted to add sliding animations, they do slide, but now the maxHeight isn't adjusted to account for the height of the elements inside of it, and as such the elements overlap and can't be seen properly.

Can I update the maxHeight of each element only when the button is active to achieve the desired result, and if so, what would be the best way to accomplish that?

```js
var buttonListLB = document.getElementsByClassName("button-lightblue");
var buttonListB = document.getElementsByClassName("button-blue");
var buttonListDB = document.getElementsByClassName("button-darkblue");
var i;
var j;
var k;

function openDropbox() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

  if (panel.style.display === "block") { //The parent's status should be considered here
    panel.style.display = "none";
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    panel.style.display = "block";
    panel.style.maxHeight = (panel.scrollHeight) + "px";
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < buttonListLB.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < buttonListB.length; j++) {
    for (k = 0; k < buttonListDB.length; k++) {
      buttonListDB[k].addEventListener("click", openDropbox);
    }
    buttonListB[j].addEventListener("click", openDropbox);
  }
  buttonListLB[i].addEventListener("click", openDropbox);
}
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  padding: 2px;
  height: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.button-lightblue {
  background-color: #0287c5;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button-lightblue:after {
  content: '⏵';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.active,
.button-lightblue:hover {
  background-color: #0085d8;
}

.active:after {
  content: "⏷";
}

.button-blue {
  background-color: #005aab;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button-blue:after {
  content: '⏵';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.active,
.button-blue:hover {
  background-color: #0085d8;
}

.active:after {
  content: "⏷";
}

.button-darkblue {
  background-color: #003c71;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button-darkblue:after {
  content: '⏵';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.active,
.button-darkblue:hover {
  background-color: #0085d8;
}

.active:after {
  content: "⏷";
}

.button-link {
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 0;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.accordion-content {
  padding: 0 2px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.dropbox-content {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0 2px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  max-height: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 35%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.dropbox-content a {
  color: #0085d8;
  font-family: Arial;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
}

.dropbox-content font {
  color: #0085d8;
  font-family: Arial;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
}

.additional-content {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #003c71;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <button class="button-lightblue"> Top Button 1</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <button class="button-blue"> Middle Button 1</button>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <button class="button-darkblue"> Bottom Button 1</button>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <font face="Arial">
            <a href="" class="button-link" target="_blank">Dead Link</a>
          </font>
        </div>
        <button class="button-darkblue"> Bottom Button 2</button>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <font face="Arial">
            <a href="" class="button-link" target="_blank">Dead Link</a>
          </font>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="button-blue"> Middle Button 2</button>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <button class="button-darkblue"> Bottom Button 3</button>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <font face="Arial">
            <a href="" class="button-link" target="_blank">Dead Link</a>
          </font>
        </div>
        <button class="button-darkblue"> Bottom Button 4</button>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <font face="Arial">
            <a href="" class="button-link" target="_blank">Dead Link</a>
          </font>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Running the above snippet should make the problem very clear. I'm open to any suggestions, thank you in advance.

EDIT: I removed an erroneous function I left in the script by mistake.